# Econnreset when starting e2e on cypress

Tags: node.js, cypress

When I start the test here:

[image]

I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. I have edited your question. Please read how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you try this? https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/18947#issuecomment-991901414

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.